# Triggering the other component function from my component using @viewChild

Tags: angular

In my app I have multiple components, in that I have to trigger the other component function from one component. There is no relationship between two components.In this case tried with @viewChild.

While calling the function getting the TypeError: Cannot read property 'showHelp' of undefined error.

Is @viewChild only for parent and child component interaction, is this possible only via service?

```
import { ChangeListComponent } from '../change-list/change-list.component';
    export class WeatherReportComponent {
        @ViewChild(ChangeListComponent) private changeListComponent:ChangeListComponent;
        showHelp(){
            this.changeListComponent.showHelp();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the Child component where you can send some values on button click, drop down selection to parent component. On button click we will trigger `childToParent` event from child component with name as value

```
import { Component, Input, Output,EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  template: `
    <input type="textbox" [(ngModel)]='masterName'>
    <button (click)="sendToParent(masterName)" >sendToParent</button>
  `
})
export class AppChildComponent {
  //getting value from parent to child
  @Input('master') masterName: string;

  @Output() childToParent = new EventEmitter<String>();

  sendToParent(name){
    this.childToParent.emit(name);
  }
}
```

Below is the master component where `childToParent` method is triggered from child component with the emitted value.

```
import { Component, Output,EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  //passing values from parent to child
  master = "child";

  //Getting value from child
  childToParent(name){
    this.master=name;
  }

}
```

[You can refer this link for working version](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-parent-child-interaction)

Comment: In my app there is no link between two components.

Comment: what do like to share between the components? if you want to share some data between the components use service.